# Toolbar doesn't responsive to scroll events

Tags: android

I want to hide/show the Toolbar when ListView is scrolling. I have CorrdinatorLayout with Toolbar included in. I add the app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" attribute to the Toolbar. Then I have Listview inside content_min layout with RelativeLayout with app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" attribute. I included the content_main layout inside CoordinatorLayout -Toolbar not responsive to scroll events on listview. Does this Feature work with RecyclerView only and not listview?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.era.www.onmovie.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

content_main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.era.www.onmovie.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling behavior works with `RecyclerView` but not out-of-box with `ListView`.  This is because the scrolling behavior needs a scrolling component that implements the `NestedScrollingChild` interface.  This interface is implemented by `RecyclerView` but not `ListView`.

My recommendation would be to convert your `ListView` adapter to a `RecyclerView` adapter and use `RecyclerView`.

Supposedly there are some ways to put a `ListView` inside a `NestedScrollView` which will give the scrolling behavior.  I don't recommend this, but if you search SO you can find some solutions for wrapping your `ListView` inside a `NestedScrollView` and getting the toolbar to scroll.